# Retrieve all attributes from Bean in XHTML

Tags: java, spring, annotations, javabeans

I currently have a component like the following example:

```
@Component("infoData")
public class infoDataClass(){
    protected Integer age;
    protected String name;
    protected String address;
```

with their getters and setters...

And in my xhtml I access those attributes in the following way :

```
<div
  id="infoContainer"
  data-age="#{infoData.age}"
  data-address="#{infoData.address}"
  data-name="#{infoData.name}"
></div>
```

And I get them successfully. My question is, instead of accessing them one by one, how could i get them all together? I need to add 5-6 and maybe even more attributes in the future and it will become really messy if I continue like this.

In my frontend (vue) I parse them in the following way:

```
 const age= $(containerElement).attr('data-age');
 const name= $(containerElement).attr('data-name');
```

Comment: What do you mean by get them all? The Vue is binded to a specific attribute...so you must define data-age and data-address, data-name.

Comment: Hello SMA thanks for the comment. What I mean is if there's a way to return a list of the current attributes from my java class and retrieve it as an object in vue.

Something like data-info-container = '#{infoData.container} where container would be an object with keys age address and name and their corresponding values. Thanks in advance !

Comment: If that would be a bad practice feel free to correct me, I just thought instead of having 10 lines of code in my XHTML for each and every attribute, pass it as one whole object with key value pairs and access whatever I need from that container in vue. So pass the infoContainer into Vue and then get infoContainer.age or infoContainer.name etc.etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by serializing my object by using Gson.

```
public String getJsonChartData() {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    return gson.toJson(this);
}
```